# Select polygons of an object by color in Blender

Tags: colors, polygon, blender, mesh

I have a scan of a body and I want to select it's t-shirt only but all the polygons belong to the same object. Is there a way to select polygons by color and then delete those unselected, so I can have an obj containing only the t-shirt?

edit: I want something similar than you do with gimp or photoshop with 2d images, selecting pixels by colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 3D scan would most likely use a photo that is uv mapped onto a mesh object. In this setup there is no easy way to select part of the mesh based on the material colour. In fact each polygon in the mesh maps to an area of an image that can contain any number of colours.

There are several [selection tools available](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#selection-tools), I expect using box select <kbd>B</kbd> and/or circle select <kbd>C</kbd> (sometimes called paint select) and then using <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the vertices/faces you don't want would be the approach to use.

It is possible to use multiple materials on a model with each face being assigned a [different material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/517/935), if this is the case you have an option to select or deselect the faces using a material in the material properties.